# SQL Query not working due to column name error however column exists

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

I am having a problem with the query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM `pageindex`
    FULL JOIN `pages` ON `pageindex`.`url` = `pages`.`page`
WHERE `pageindex`.`url` IS NULL;
```

I have also tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM pageindex
    FULL JOIN pages ON pageindex.url = pages.page
WHERE pageindex.url IS NULL;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'pageindex.url' in 'where clause'
```

But I'm not understanding why, when the column does exist, here is the columns from the table:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| url          | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| keywords     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description  | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_updated | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| heading      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| textcontent  | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| htmlcontent  | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| audiencetype | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Hope you can help,

Thanks

Comment: Didn't know if it would affect the syntax @Strawberry

Comment: `FULL JOIN` in MySQL? This feature seems not currently supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because FULL JOIN is not supported in MySQL, your query is interpreted as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `pageindex` AS full
  JOIN `pages` ON `pageindex`.`url` = `pages`.`page`
 WHERE `pageindex`.`url` IS NULL;
```